# Can I fight The Leviathan again?

Tags: borderlands-2

The Leviathan (in the Scarlett DLC) was an okay boss fight with some great rewards (reminiscent of Knoxx's Armory almost), but I don't see any way to fight him again. Is there any way to challenge him again and get another crack at his loot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only fight him twice per play through, once for the story and a second time by starting the side quest at the Oasis bounty board.

But there's a way to get the treasure loot even if it's dead again and again

Comment: This glitch also works with Xbox 360.

Comment: Was this done on pc or ps3? Because I want to know if this is possible on ps3.

Answer (score 2):

As axton, do not throw your turret at the corner wall. it breaks the box for hidden walls and will cause you to fall your death, and you cannot use the hidden walls after that.