# Scaling Borderlands 2 chests in DLC

Tags: borderlands-2

I've played through Playthrough 1, went and killed the Leviathan in the Pirates DLC, played a bit of Playthrough 2 (1/4th of the way), then I went and beat the Pirates DLC on that playthrough. I was lvl 45, so the loot at the end of the DLC was of that lvl. After playing some more in normal Playthrough 2 (up to lvl 50), I decided I wanted better loot, so I went to farm the Leviathan chests again, but it is still lvl 45. How do I get it to scale up to me at lvl 50?

Answer (score 3):

As I note [in this related answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/86395/11920), a mission, rewards and mission enemies scale to the level when the mission was *taken*. If you take a scaled mission at level 45 and level to level 50, unfortunately the mission and its rewards will still be level 45. This is why it's important to wait until you're maxed out in Playthrough 2 before taking on many sidequests.

Comment: Noted and informative (that thread gets better with every read!), but my question remains. Is there a way to re-do Pirates on 2.5 (which I don't know too much about, having only done a little of PL2 on BL1), or is the best way to go about getting a lvl 50 loot farm by raising an alternative character to 50 and doing Pirates at the appropriate lvl? Thank you!

Comment: @jwx you mean totally redo quests? You can't. Starting a new character would work though. There is however a way to farm the leviathan's drops again, if you haven't already completed the second quest to kill him: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89581/can-i-fight-the-leviathan-again

Comment: Well, totally re-do them, but in a higher playthrough. As I haven't done 2.5 in any borderlands game before, I don't think I fully understand it. Does it open up after killing the Warrior on PL2? Or does 2.5 begin when a character hits lvl 50? I am wondering if I can beat PL2, go to PL2.5, and then get Pirates done properly at lvl 50 (and thereby have lvl 50 loot). The farming strategy would be great if I could get the loot to 50 on my current character. I'm guessing I might just have to settle for an alt character doing it all.

Comment: @jwx Beating warrior unlocks playthrough 2.5, but you still need to be level 50 for the missions to scale that high (but you should be lvl 50 by the time you beat warrior)