# How to farm Pirate's Booty challenge

Tags: borderlands-2

A challenge "Pirate's Booty" asks you to open lots (25/75/150/250/375) of [Pirate Weapon Chests](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Lootable_object#Pirate_Weapon_Chest).

Obviously, most pirate chests in existence are in the Leviathan's treasure room, but it is only accessible twice during the main and the encore quest.

What is the best route to farm pirate chests outside quests? Is there an obscure way through quests that yields lots of chests?

Comment: I'd say the best way to get the challange is just getting all the chests in the different areas you know of, then shutting off/back on the game and getting them again

Comment: I'd say completing all the sidequests first (including both Leviathan runs) but I don't think that's enough to do it just from questing. There's a few locations of them but I'm not sure where the closest ones to a spawn point are

Comment: I've completed all quests once and i'm at something like level 2: 65/75... Completing them on PT2 definitely won't yield much (most likely level 3 is 150 chests)...

Comment: Oh wow it requires far more chests than I recall then. If this glitch still works it's your best bet: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89581/can-i-fight-the-leviathan-again I couldn't reproduce it earlier this week though, I don't know if they patched it or if I was just doing it wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most chests in one place are in **Leviathan's Lair** - 14 of them, countung the one in secret chamber.
Leviathan's treasure room is accessible twice during the questline, plus there is a glitch to break into it later. There are hosts of instructions on Youtube, but I've found [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JdqGfiIChII) to be the easiest.

I'm about to start a second playthrough of Captain Scarlett, and will try to mark down all chests I find. If anyone has that information, let's work together!

#### Wurmwater

- 1 chest on the refinery supports, to be jumped to from a moving elevator.

#### Hayter's Folly

- 2 chests near vending machines in the middle of the map, in the water under a rock.
- 1 chest after Sandman, on the right.

#### The Rustyards

- 1 chest in the middle of first large shantytown ship you go through.
- 1 chest in top end of the second large shantytown ship, behind a shack.
- 1 chest on the last ship in the center of the map, right at the turret on the deck.
- 1 chest on the last ship in the center of the map, on the mast you climb for The Crow's Nest challenge.

#### Washburne Refinery

- 1 chest just before the Hyperius arena re-spawn point.
- 1 chest a little past the H3RL-E's lair.
- 1 chest in a secret room above the Arm (jump across the drop when returning from H3RL-E).

#### Magnys Lighthouse

- 1 chest on a wooden platform under a house near Maroonie's Secret Stash.
- 2 chests atop the lighthouse itself.

#### Leviathan's Lair

- 14 chests in the treasure room. See [glitch](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JdqGfiIChII).

#### Oasis

- 1 chest where you get the Horrid Hideaway challenge
- 1 chest at the building across the bridge in the middle of the map
- 1 chest in the southeastern most part of the map (Canyon Deserter Camp).

Answer (score 2):

One more in The Rustyards. After you get the one on the last ship, the one in front of the turrent. Climb the mast by jumping back and forth from one side to the other. When you get to the crossbeam you not only get a challenge "Crow's Nest" you also will see another chest if you look NW.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 more Pirate Chests in Wurmwater, making it one of the best places to farm.  Directly across from the chest on the refinery supports is the giant satellite dish area where the "Don't Copy That Floppy" quest takes place.  In this small area there are 2 Pirate Chests.  After making your way up and around to the satellite dish, proceed across it to the South West (headed back toward the refinery).  There is 1 Pirate Chest at the beginning of the boardwalk which runs above the path you walked in on, and another (#2) at the far end of the same boardwalk above where you entered, directly below the Vault Symbol on the wall.